# How can I subscribe to the Azure Service Bus deadletter queue in MassTransit?

Tags: azure, masstransit, servicebus, dead-letter

I'm new to MassTransit and Azure Service Bus.

When a received message fails due to an unexpected exception, or maybe an unlucky power failure, I would like the message to go to the deadletter queue (after N retries).

I also want to listen for new messages on the the deadletter queue. The goal is to do some housekeeping/cleanup/whatever whenever there has been an error.

I can't get my consumer to actually consume deadletter messages. Messages move to the deadletter queue no problem... I just can't get masstransit to receive them.

Here's the relevant bits of my startup (.net6, program.cs, inside public static void Main(..)):

```
// All aboard
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(config =>
{
    // Does not really apply since we name the queue explicitly
    config.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    // A consumer (fully configured later)
    config.AddConsumer<NormalHandler>();
    config.AddConsumer<DeadletterHandler>();

    // One service bus please
    config.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
    {
        // Service bus connection string
        cfg.Host(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ServiceBus"));

        // Our request endpoint
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("work-request", cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ConfigureConsumer<NormalHandler>(context);
            cfg.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueDeadLetterTransport();
            cfg.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueErrorTransport();
        });

        // Our request endpoint for unexpected errors
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("work-request/$DeadLetterQueue", cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ConfigureConsumer<DeadletterHandler>(context);
        });

        // Finish up the config
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
```

And my fake (for this question) handlers and message:

```
public record WorkRequest(Guid id);

public class NormalHandler : IConsumer<WorkRequest>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<WorkRequest> context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class DeadletterHandler : IConsumer<WorkRequest>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<WorkRequest> context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Start of the logging looks good:

```
[07:45:33 INF] Configured endpoint work-request, Consumer: Hahah.NormalHandler
[07:45:34 INF] Configured endpoint $DeadLetterQueue, Consumer: Hahah.DeadletterHandler
```

It is odd the endpoint name for deadletter just shows $DeadLetterQueue... I would almost have expected "work-request/$DeadLetterQueue".

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the logs, I don't think the receive endpoint name with the slash is even valid.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Added the logs. If slash is not valid... what name should be used?

Comment: I don't recommend creating endpoints on DLQ's.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Can you expand on why not? It seems like the perfect place for handling unexpected errors, including problems with frameworks et al (eg. message delivered to MassTransit then server crashes... N times in a row... can't rely on MassTransit's error handling because the crash killed everything).

Comment: And what happens when your consumer fails consuming from the DLQ? Rinse, repeat.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Thanks for the insight. The _error queue it is and maybe regular monitor of the dlq which should only contain truly exceptional issues (correct? please confirm). If you want to add an answer I'll do the necessary :)